# Purpose of Facebook App Id and Secret Key

Tags: facebook-oauth

What is the purpose of using app Id and app secret in facebook? 
which algorithm is used for generating that secret key?

Comment: The App ID is a public identifier for your application.  It's something consuming code can use to identify the application.  The App Secret is a private key your code can use to identify you as the owner of the application, so you can perform operations non-owners should not be able to perform.  If the algorithm for generating the secret was known, it wouldn't be a secret now would it?

Comment: @user3354411 : Without knowing the inputs of that algorithm "How can you find the secret key ?" . The algorithms used by Facebook, Google has been known to everyone. But their inputs to the algorithm NO BODY knowns it ( Input Meaning PLAIN TEXT in this case ). Itz hard to break it. Dont worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook app Id, app secret key will be generated automatically when you register a Facebook App successfully. Therefor, they used to identify your Facebook app and when you need the app to authenticate using Oauth.